# Creating a pop up with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do three things.

Stop it saying `an embedded page says`, so it's just a blank white box, give the `f` and `t` a link, and a class or ID so I can target them with CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body
<button 
onclick="myFunction()"><div 
class="containercross"><div 
class="cross1"><div 
class="cross2">
</div></div></div>
</a></button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("f, t");
}</script><html><body>
```

The `f` should link Facebook, the `t twitter` and the cross just generate the pop up onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular `alert()` dialogs cannot be modified.  There is text, and that's it.

You have to create your modal dialog with HTML and CSS.

There actually is a convenient `<dialog>` element now, but it only works in Chrome and variants.

Comment: Ok. Thanks....how would i structure a <dialog> pop up involving no JavaScript?

Comment: @New To be clear, you can use JavaScript, but you can't use only the `alert()` function.  Once you have your `<dialog>` element on the page, you can do something like `document.querySelector('dialog').showModal()`.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog